# SSH@0 Task in Azure DevOps "Could not chdir to home directory /home/***: No such file or directory"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssh, azure-pipelines

I am generally unfamiliar with SSH, and shell commands in general.

I've set up a remote Windows machine as an SSH endpoint in Azure DevOps under the Service Connections in Project Settings. I am now trying to execute the SSH@0 task within a new pipeline I'm building.

Code:

```
- task: SSH@0
   inputs:
     sshEndpoint: 'windows endpoint'
     runOptions: 'inline'
     inline: |
          *shell code to execute*
```

Upon running the pipeline, the job reports:

`Trying to establish an SSH connection to ... Successfully connected.`

But then:

`##[error]Could not chdir to home directory /home/***: No such file or directory`

I'm aware that the /home directory is used by Linux but not Windows, so is the task assuming I'm remoting into a Linux machine? Is there a step or pipeline property I'm missing in my setup?

I've tried two other ways of remoting in the YAML pipeline including:

- Entering an SSH public key into ADO and using the ssh command in a PowerShell task
- Creating a New-PSSession and using the -ToSession attribute on certain commands

They've respectively failed because:

- "Host key verification failed" for no discernible reason.
- "The WinRM client cannot process the request." This error further detailed configuring the hosts by running winrm.cmd, but executing the command did nothing.

Comment: Would you please share the sample shell code to reproduce the issue? If you run the same shell code on your remote machine, what's the result? If you want to run scripts on Windows remote machine, you may consider [PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 - PowerShell on target machines v3 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions for Windows in [SSH v0 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ssh-v0?view=azure-pipelines).

1. Check your **shell code to execute**. Maybe it contains the `chdir` command.
2. Check the solution provided here: [SSH task fails on Windows Server 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17991)
3. If nothing helped, you may raise an issue for the task developers: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues